# What do I do when publish revision doesn't work?

Tags: publish, revision

In Eko studio. Me and my classmates have been trying to publish our works since yesterday. My publish gets to about 50% and then it fails. What's going on? Most of us are located in Sweden but the same problem is with students located in the USA. Please let us know what we can do. Thank you!

I tried to publish a new revision.

Comment: What do teacher or Eko Studio support team say about that? What is the publishing status exactly? Have you cheked the [Eko Studio guide](https://guides.eko.com/article/publishing-status/) ?